# authenticate angularjs and subscribe to courses

Tags: json, security, angularjs, subscription

I just started with Angularjs and I was wondering how I should proceed to make a simple app to let users subscribe to a course...

Where should I keep those subscription records? For security reasons I guess a json file on the server is not the way to go? Or not?

Users are on the intranet and a variable with their userid will be used to authenticate...

Any suggestions?

I found something about auth and angularjs here:
http://frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/

Comment: Firebase is a nice solution if you just need to securely store data and retrieve it and you don't want to build your own server.

Answer (score 0):

It is a server problem so you can't solve it with AngularJS, which is pure front end framework.

If you don't want to code something on a server, there is currently a trend called "nobackend", have a look here : http://nobackend.org/

About the website you mentioned : the author also made a post about the server so you can go with it since it is also in Javascript, thus part of your abilities with JS can be reused.

http://www.frederiknakstad.com/blog/2013/08/04/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular.js-part-2/

Comment: LOL, it's the link I posted in my question :)

Comment: Ok, I misread and corrected. The link is now about the server part

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, the nobackend.org seems to work with online services most of the time... but my app should be deployed on an intranet without internet connection :s

Comment: Then you need a server, with a way to persist data. JSON file can work but it won't scale easily. Try a database instead.